# Oscilloscope sensors (as a system)

Tags: sensor, oscilloscope, control-system, system

Today in Introduction to Engineering class my teacher picked me to name what components are in the Oscilloscope, in terms of: Input Components, Display Components, Actuators, Sensors, and Controllers. I got stuck when naming sensors in Oscilloscope system, so I got back home and did some research and found some sensors named ABS and hall effect sensors are they integrated sensors? or are they external sensors? 
Anyways I thought the question to be very general, I would appreciate an Oscilloscope manual or component list.
Sorry, I'm still a freshman I don't know if my question makes sense.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: A scope has regulated power supplies. That on/off switch is an actuator. How about the cooling fan? speed controlled, with temp sensor?

Comment: @analogsystemsrf If it was an exam question, I would write this answer supposing it is a tricky one!

Comment: @analogsystemsrf can the synchronizing system be considered as a controller?

Comment: @analogsystemsrf An on/off switch is an input component, not an actuator. An actuator is a component which is driven by a control system -- like the fan in the cooling system you described.

Comment: @duskwuff like a pump in the kidney dialysis machine for example.

Comment: Are knobs and buttons sensors?

Comment: @BrianDrummond Generally not -- "sensor" is usually used to describe inputs which are part of the control loop.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The ontology that your professor is using (input/output, actuators, sensors, and controllers) doesn't really apply to an oscilloscope. It's intended to apply to a feedback control system -- like the engine controller in a car, or a self-balancing robot, or a chemical plant. Basically, a device which reacts to changes in some external system, typically in ways that affect that system.

An oscilloscope isn't that kind of device. It's purely a measurement tool -- it's meant to *observe* the behavior of the device it's connected to, not to control it! As such, it doesn't have any actuators, nor any controller (since there's no actuator). The only one of these components that an oscilloscope arguably has is a set of sensors, which is the probes -- or, more precisely, the ADC internal to the 'scope which senses voltage.

Comment: Yes!! That what I was thinking about.

Comment: Actually, there could be a sensor in an expensive scope, a sensor that registers/records the instrument acceleration, so the manufacturer can refuse to make warranty repairs if you drop the scope off a truck, but claim that it stopped working on its own.

Comment: @AliChen A sensor of that type wouldn't be part of a control system, though.

Comment: It will be a major part of INVENTORY and QA control system :-)

Comment: @duskwuff hey man, i just wanted to tell you that i an got A+ for the answer you have suggested, that is exactly what my professor wanted to hear, thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

This question is a little oblique, because you can hook up any kind of sensor to an oscilloscope. Oscilloscopes measure voltage fast (hundreds of MHz or GHz) with 'low' resolution at 8 to 16 bits (roughly).

Since they measure voltage any sensor that outputs a voltage can be measured. Sensors that measure current like a hall effect sensor usually need an amplifier to convert it to a voltage. Some oscilloscope companies make hall effect or current sensors that plug into oscilloscopes but they still output a voltage.

Comment: That means that an Oscilloscope doesn't have a sensor inside, I mean you can hook up a sensor to it depending on what you are doing?

Comment: Yeah, you can hook up any sensor, but your still just measuring a voltage. The probe inputs are high impedance and don't pull a lot of current.

Comment: Thank you, It would be great if link me to some of the sensors so that I can know their use.

Comment: You can find info on the sensors by searching the product pages of some major scope manufacturers like tektronics, Rohde & Schwarz, Keysight and others.

Comment: 'Scopes measure *voltage AND time*, so timing circuits are also required. Time (in modern 'scopes) is determined by counting regular pulses of a crystal oscillator.

Comment: @glen_geek sorry, I'm trying to balance this out for a beginner, I'm not getting technical. I did say MHz and GHz which would imply time